# Compare two pandas dataframes and create a third where at least 2 values or more are equal

Tags: python, pandas

**Dataframe with drawings from lottery**

df1

```
Date       first second third fourth fifth
1/20/2001    1      2     9     15    30
1/21/2002    5       15   20     23    31
```

and thousands of more entries

**Dataframe with tickets to compare**
df2

```
first second third fourth fifth
1       5      9     20     21
```

and about 10 more entries

Comment: Whats the expected output, are you matching on dates?

Comment: i think he wants all rows of df1 which have at least two values in common with any of the rows in df2

Comment: What luigigi suggested is exactly what I want. DF3 should be an extraction of the rows from df1, including the dates, which have a least 2 values or more matching the values from df2. DF2 has no dates. thanks